# Showing that a bilinear form is coercive

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $I = (0, 1)$ and $H_0^2 (I)$ the closure of $C_c^\infty (I)$ in $W^{2, 2} (I)$. Consider 
$$a : H_0^2 (I) \times H_0^2 (I) \to \mathbb{R}$$
defined by
$$a(u, v) = \underset{I}{\int} u''(x) v''(x) dx.$$
Show that *a* is coercive, i. e. there is a constant *c* such that
$$a (u, u) \geq c \|u\|^2_{H_0^2 (I)}, \;\; \forall u \in H_0^2 (I).$$
We have
$$u \in H_0^2 (I) : u \in W^{2, 2} (I) \;\; u = u' = 0 \;\; \text{on} \;\; \partial I $$
and
$$a(u, u) = \|u ''\|^2_{L^2(I)}$$
$$\|u\|^2_{H_0^2 (I)} = \|u\|^2_{L^2(I)} + \|u'\|^2_{L^2(I)} + \|u''\|^2_{L^2(I)} =  \|u\|^2_{L^2(I)} + \|u'\|^2_{L^2(I)} + a(u, u). $$
Also we have the Poincar$\acute{e}$ inequality, which says that there is a constant *c* such that
$$\|u\|_{W^{1, 2}(I)} = \|u\|^2_{L^2(I)} + \|u'\|^2_{L^2(I)} \leq c \|u'\|_{L^2(I)}. $$

Can someone please give me a hint on how to conclude that *a* is coercive?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $u' \in H_0^1(I)$, you can apply Poincaré to $u'$. This gives $$\|u'\|_{H^1} \le C \, \|u''\|_{L^2}.$$
Can you conclude?

Comment: Yes. Thank you!